# Inserting various paragraphs into one content control Office-js

Tags: office-js

I am working on a Office-js project, currently I am inserting Html into the word document.  The Html may contain various paragraphs and images, or it may contain just text.  Currently I am aware you can insert a paragraph or image into a content control, however I would like to know if it is possible to insert the entire selection into a content control.  I am aware I can do something like this

```
 var contentControl = paragraphs.items[0].insertContentControl();
```

However I was wondering if it would be possible to insert a whole html insertion into a content control with out breaking it up into paragraphs.  A little like inserting the Html as an object into one content control.

**Update Current Code**

```
function tagInsertedContent(contentObject) {
Word.run(function (context) {
    var contentTitle = contentObject.Name;
    var modDate = contentObject.LastModifiedTime;
    var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    context.load(paragraphs, 'text');
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        var paragraph;
        var contententControls;
        for (var x = 0; x < paragraphs.items.length; x++) {
            paragraph = paragraphs.items[x]
            if (paragraph.text) {
                contententControls = paragraph.insertContentControl();
                contententControls.title = contentTitle;
                contententControls.tag = modDate;
                contententControls.color ="#ff0000";
            }
        }
    })
    .then(context.sync())
    .catch(function (error) {
        error.ErrorLocation = "Items Not Tagged";
        error.ErrorCode = error.debugInfo.errorLocation;
        error.ErrorMessage = "Content was not tagged correctly";
        error.Selection = contentObject.Name;
        ErrorHandler(error);
    })
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried inserting the content control and then the HTML? you can also insert HTML into a content control!

for instance you can do something like:

```js
   function insertHTMLinToContentControl() {

        var myHtml = "<b> Whatever HTML you want to insert </b>";

        Word.run(function (ctx) {
            
            var myContentControl = ctx.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
            myContentControl.insertHtml(myHtml, "replace");
            return ctx.sync();
        });

                  
    }
```

the above code inserts a content control in the current selection and then inserts a (simple on this example :)) html.

Hope this helps and happy coding!!
Juan.

Comment: Great way of doing it, I was think of loading paragraph but this will definitely work. I put up the function which I had, but I will take your way seems cleaner.